# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' when using the bash shell to execute. When using python interpreter the code works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto, rds

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3    
import boto.rds2    
rds2_conn=boto.rds2.connect_to_region(region_name="us-east")
cs= rds2_conn.describe_db_instances(db_instance_identifier=None)
print(cs)
```

I want to get all the running instances in a AWS environment. I am using python 3.3. 
i had used boto.rds earlier which has a method called rds2.get_all_dbinstances().
But i am migrating now to rds2. when i try to run the above code using python interpreter **usage :python filename.py  :** i get no error. the program works fine. But using Bash shell **usage :./filename.py  :**
 i get the error :

```
TypeError: File "/Users/heninkarkada/Documents/repositories/jaws/b.py", line 5, in <module>
    raw=con.describe_db_instances(db_instance_identifier=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/rds2/layer1.py", line 1512, in describe_db_instances
    path='/', params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/rds2/layer1.py", line 3764, in _make_request
    return json.loads(body)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' at line no:3
```

Can anyone tell me why this thing is happening?
Advance thanks

Comment: Can you manually pass a path to `describe_db_instances`? If so, do that then rerun. My guess is it has to do with bash passing a bytestring while the python interpreter passes a native str.

Comment: You might want to check that you're using the same python.  do `which python` and `which python3` point you to the same thing?

Comment: @Logan- i m trying to retrieve all running dv_instances which is connected to the specific region'

Comment: @mgilson python shows - /usr/bin/python and python 3-/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: try `python3 filename.py`. It should produce the same error.

Comment: @J.F Sebastin thats working fine, But i want my script to be run by bash shell terminal and inn pycharm. I changed the shebang to #!/usr/bin/python , now its running in shell terminal but not in pycharm :(

Comment: then try to set the shebang to `/usr/local/bin/python3` if it works. Then configure `pycharm` to use that python executable.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian- No Buddy its not working fine. Can you illustrate an example of using the json decode for my string data. I want to use python3 for this code.

Comment: @Zumbaa:  when I said *"try python3 filename.py.  It should produce the same error"* and you said *"thats working fine"*. What did you mean?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian- using python3 its not getting executed, it gives the same error. But is there a way to  use rds2 using python3 or is it still under progress?

Comment: @Zumbaa: I don't know the current status of Python 3 support for `boto` and whether there is a branch that makes `boto.rds2` work on Python 3. [I don't see Python 3 port mentioned in the docs for RDS](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/): *"Currently, all features work with Python 2.6 and 2.7. Work is under way to support Python 3.3+ in the same codebase. Modules are being ported one at a time with the help of the open source community, so please check below for compatibility with Python 3.3+."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` might be incorrect if the script is actually Python 2 script, not Python 3 script. `json` accepts bytestrings in Python 2. In Python 3, the input must be Unicode string.

The json code that fails is inside `boto` package.
boto's `setup.py` claims Python 3 support but It is possible that [boto scripts are incompatible with Python 3 yet](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2670).